# Use custom template on certain URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, multi-language

I'm building a simple two language site. I'm using Polylang for posts, and also have a custom post type, "Artist." In order to keep it simple on the back-end, I'm not using Polylang, just a few custom fields for language on each artist.

When I load site.com/artist/johnny-cash I'm using the template single-artist.php on my theme. The question is, how would I manage to load a custom template when I load, for example, site.com/en/artist/johnny-cash?

So basically, this:

site.com/artist/johnny-cash -> Loads single-artist.php (awesome)

site.com/en/artist/johnny-cash -> How do I redirect to a custom template?

Comment: how have you enabled both URLs to point to your custom post type?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you (probably didn't explained myself.) I registered a custom post type, and its slug is "artist", so WP automatically loads single-artist.php when you load /artist/john-doe

Comment: and how does visiting that URL with `/en/` prepended also result in your single post type being displayed? or does it presently 404?

Comment: Right now, it redirects to same page without /en/, like /artist/johnny-cash No idea why. I figured it should 404, but no...

Comment: WordPress tries to find what you meant to load before returning a 404, and redirects to that. so you have an additional step before you can deal with templates, and that's adding rewrite rules to make those `/en/` requests load the correct object.

Comment: @Milo Thanks. Could you point me to some documentation or example on something similar?

Comment: If you search `add_rewrite_rule` here you'll find lots of examples. I don't have time to write the code at the moment, but I can point you in a direction. When you add the rewrite rule to handle your custom post type requests with `/en/`, you can also add an extra query var, so you can identify those requests separately from the non `en` requests. then you can [filter `single_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy), check for that query var, and load a special template in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Milo on the comments, I'm gonna post my answer:

Firstly I added this rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule(  
    "en/artist/([^/]+)/?",  
    'index.php?pagename=post_type=artist&artist=$matches[1]&gal_template=en',
    "top");
```

Then this filter:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'gal_query_vars' );
function gal_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'gal_template';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Finally, I filtered the single template:

```
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
     global $post;

     if ($post->post_type == 'artist') {

            $q = get_query_var('gal_template');

            if ($q === 'en') {
                $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-artist-en.php';
            }


     }
     return $single_template;
}
```

Then on single-artist-en.php I did:

```
get_template_part('single-artist')
```

But you could do whatever you need.

Comment: Here is the actual and complete solution by the wordpress: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule